# Used to get a new public IP on MAC change, don't anymore? (Netis - Archer)

Tags: networking, router, mac-address

On my old Netis router, a really old piece of tech that came with my internet package, I could go to localhost, and change my MAC address, which would instantly provide me with a new public IP. It looks like this: e4:be:ed:79:68:88 (Changed in WAN). However, I just got a fancy new Archer router, and it has a MAC clone option, but the MAC address it shows doesn't look like the above one at all - it's E0-D5-5E-AD-AE-0B. I called my ISP, and they said you can't do that trick on new routers. I don't get it, why? Why does the MAC shown look completely different on same network, just 2 different routers? And why does changing the MAC on Netis gives me a new public IP, but doing so on Archer doesn't?

Comment: The basic reason is that ISP needs to know their customer base by IP address in case some users entertain nefarious activities on the Internet.

Comment: But I can change it easily on old router?

Comment: Which will be why they have now closed that door.

Comment: Nope, I can still do it through old router. I've actually hooked it up again.

Comment: MAC addresses are written as hexadecimal numbers. Whether they're uppercase or lowercase, or whether they're separated by dashes or colons has no effect on the address itself, in the end it's still a series of 12 hexadecimal digits. ("e0:d5:5e:ad:ae:0b" might be called IETF style, "E4-BE-ED-79-68-88" might be Windows style, "e4be.ed79.6888" is Cisco style.)

Answer (score 0):

The
[Archer C60(EU)_V3_User Guide](https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202004/20200409/1910012740_Archer%20C60_UG_V3.pdf)
(page 90) says that changing the MAC is possible in
*Advanced > Network > Internet*, MAC Clone section,
option "Use Custom MAC Address":

[image]

If this doesn't work, then there is a problem with the firmware.

You could at first do a Factory Reset (page 6) using the Reset Button.
Press and hold this button until the Power LED blinks to reset the router
to its factory default settings. You will lose any configuration that
you did to the router.

As second step, you could download the latest
[firmware](https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/archer-c60/#Firmware)
and install it (very carefully).
You will also lose here any configuration that you did.

As a last resort, you could address TP-Link Support, to find out
why this option does not work.